# How to preserve all unique combinations of values when merging columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

Given the table

```
| A | B | C | C | C | D | D |
  1   0   x   y   z   8   9
  2   4   x   b
```

What are the best available methods for returning

```
| A | B | C | D |
  1   0   x   8
  1   0   y   8
  1   0   z   8
  1   0   x   9
  1   0   y   9
  1   0   z   9
  2   4   x
  2   4   b
```

I'm pulling from csv's using pandas read_csv... not sure if I could handle it there, or with SQL, or with Python dicts.

Searched hard and couldn't find an answer.

(I'm new to this, so I might be missing something basic...)

EDIT: needs to accommodate *n* rows

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,'x','y','z',8,9]], columns=list('ABCCCDD'))

result = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
             [grp for key, grp in df.T.groupby(level=0)[0]]).to_frame(index=False)
print(result)
```

yields

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  x  8
1  1  0  x  9
2  1  0  y  8
3  1  0  y  9
4  1  0  z  8
5  1  0  z  9
```

---

If your DataFrame has more than one row:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def row_to_arrays(row, idx):
    """
    Split a row into a list of component arrays.
    idx specifies the indices at which we want to split the row
    """
    # Use row[1:] because the first item in each row is the index 
    # (which we want to ignore)
    result = np.split(row[1:], idx)
    # Filter out empty strings
    result = [arr[arr != ''] for arr in result]
    # Filter out empty arrays
    result = [arr for arr in result if len(arr)]
    return result

def arrays_to_dataframe(arrays):
    """
    Convert list of arrays to product DataFrame
    """
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arrays).to_frame(index=False) 

def df_to_row_product(df):
    # find the indices at which to cut each row
    idx = pd.DataFrame(df.columns).groupby(0)[0].agg(lambda x: x.index[0])[1:]
    data = [arrays_to_dataframe(row_to_arrays(row, idx))
            for row in df.itertuples()]
    result = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True).fillna('')
    return result

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,'x','y','z',8,9],
                   [2,4,'x','b','','','']], columns=list('ABCCCDD'))

print(df_to_row_product(df))
```

yields

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  x  8
1  1  0  x  9
2  1  0  y  8
3  1  0  y  9
4  1  0  z  8
5  1  0  z  9
6  2  4  x   
7  2  4  b
```

Comment: Could do `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([g.values[0] for k, g in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)]).to_frame(index=False)` without transposing externally.

Comment: so this is interesting, but we've lost the header names.  Also, I still can't get it to work for my other dataset... result only shows 3 rows and 2 columns from a dataset with 3 unique columns, and 61 rows. ...could you provide a multi-line version, to make it easier to troubleshoot?

Comment: I think I see the problem, my example gave a single row, but I need to accommodate multiple rows of data (question updated)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one possible solution using a little preprocessing and `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product 

prod = list(product(*df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1)\
                  .apply(lambda x: x.values.reshape(-1, )).tolist()))
prod
[(1, 0, 'x', 8),
 (1, 0, 'x', 9),
 (1, 0, 'y', 8),
 (1, 0, 'y', 9),
 (1, 0, 'z', 8),
 (1, 0, 'z', 9)]

df = pd.DataFrame(prod, columns=list('ABCD'))\
                 .sort_values('D').reset_index(drop=1)
df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  x  8
1  1  0  y  8
2  1  0  z  8
3  1  0  x  9
4  1  0  y  9
5  1  0  z  9
```

Comment: I thought of setting ['A','B'] as index then apply cartesian. This ones good

Comment: getting a SegFault with the full dataset on the prod= line

Comment: @uxmatthew You must have a great many columns, in which case this is probably not going to help you. Apologies.